# Move an array element from one document to another in same collection

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to move an array element from one array in one document to another array in another document within the same collection and delete the element from the original array it was moved from.

```js
// Document 1
{
   _id: ObjectId("67dc90594947be000838f7a7"),
   employment: [
       {
          employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000838f7c8",
          type: "Full time",
          salary: 1010101
       }
           ///... other employments
    ]
}
```

```js
// Document 2
{
   _id: ObjectId("67dc90594947be000830a1f8"),
   employment: [
          {
             employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000738f7c1",
             type: "Part time",
             salary: 11011111
          }
          ///... other employments
   ]
}
```

I need to move one of the employment element from **Document 1** to **Document 2**. And I need to delete that moved element from **Document 1**.
`employmentId` is used to identify which employment to move. And `_id` is used to identify from which document to move to which document.

**Example payload**

```js
const updatePayload = {
   fromDoc: "67dc90594947be000838f7a7",
   toDoc: "67dc90594947be000830a1f8",
   employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000838f7c8",
}
```

**Expected Result**

```js
// employment from Document 1 is moved Document 2

// Document 1
{
   _id: ObjectId("67dc90594947be000838f7a7"),
   // The employment was moved to another doc and is now empty
   employment: [ ]
}

//Document 2
{
   _id: ObjectId("67dc90594947be000830a1f8"),
   employment: [
          {
             employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000738f7c1",
             type: "Part time",
             salary: 11011111
          },
          // The element that was moved!
          {
             employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000838f7c8",
             type: "Full time",
             salary: 1010101
          }
          ///... other employments
    ]
}
```

Comment: please add a  key in both the document so it will help in writing query apart from _id  to help index document.

Comment: What kind of key are you talking about? Isn't _id already indexed?